# C++ List<T> to Python List

Tags: c++, python, boost, type-conversion, boost-python

I'm writing a wrapper for an existing C++ library which utilizes list where T is a custom struct. I've been advised to utilize vector instead of list, but I'm trying to avoid modifying the library.

In order to better grok the scenario, I've make a simple application, using a list as a proxy for registering a to-python conversion (it is fine to be read only).

My current implementation compiles fine, python imports it fine, the object can be created, but when I call the data member, it errors.

python shell output:

```
In [1]: import my_list

In [2]: x = my_list.Bob()

In [3]: x.foos
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2f015d13a87d> in <module>()
----> 1 x.foos

TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >
```

C++ file:

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#ifndef FOREACH
    #define FOREACH BOOST_FOREACH
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;

template<typename T>
struct list_to_list
{
    static PyObject* convert(const std::list<T>& src)
    {
        boost::python::list result;
        FOREACH (const T& val, src)
        {
            result.append(val);
        }

        return incref(result.ptr());
    }
};

struct Bob
{
    std::list<int> foos;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_list)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    to_python_converter<std::list<int>, list_to_list<int> >();

    class_<Bob>("Bob")
        .def_readonly("foos", &Bob::foos)
    ;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#topythonconversionfailed), properties exposed via `def_readonly()`, `def_readwrite()`, and `add_property()` with default policies will not use custom converters.  To resolve this, replace `def_readonly()` and `def_readwrite()` with `add_property()`, providing a [`boost::python::return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html#return_value_policy-spec) with a type of [`boost::python::return_by_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_by_value.html#return_by_value-spec).

In the original code, it would be:

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_list)
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  to_python_converter<std::list<int>, list_to_list<int> >();

  class_<Bob>("Bob")
    .add_property("foos", make_getter(&Bob_foos,
        return_value_policy<return_by_value>())) 
    ;
}
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace python = boost::python;

/// @brief Type to convert from an iterable to a Python list.
template <typename T>
struct list_to_list
{
  static PyObject* convert(const std::list<T>& container)
  {
    python::list result;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const T& value, container)
      result.append(value);
    return python::incref(result.ptr());
  }
};

/// @brief mockup type.
struct Spam
{
  Spam()
  {
    foos = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3)(5);
  }

  std::list<int> foos;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  // Enable std::list<int> to Python list conversion.
  python::to_python_converter<std::list<int>, list_to_list<int> >();

  python::class_<Spam>("Spam")
    .add_property("foo", python::make_getter(&Spam::foos,
          python::return_value_policy<python::return_by_value>()))
    ;
}
```

And the resulting usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> spam.foo
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: It worked for me but I didn't have this issue on another project : I achieved to use def_readwrite for a member for which there is a converter but no declared class_. I can't find where it doesn't work here when it work on another situation. Is this a recent change of boost::python ?